# How can I install WebMatrix 3 in a standalone PC?

Tags: webmatrix, web-platform-installer

I need to install webmatrix 3 in a pc without internet connection.

I have win7 64bit.

so i downloaded webmatrix x64 exe and all his dependencies and services exe/msi files - include web platform installer.

I installed all and run the webmatrix app but an message box pop up and said that I need to have the latest webPI installed (4.6 in this days..). 
But it is a problem because the wpilauncher.exe file (webPI installer file) install version 4.0 for some reaseon, i think it because I dont have internet accsess.

so?
help, thx.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

WebMatrix needs an active internet connection to install since it pulls in some other required services from the Web Platform Installer.

Quote:

> "..WebMatrix needs other components installed to function correctly,
>   and those are all pulled in by Web Platform Installer automatically.
>   In that sense, the true installer is not really "offline"."

Source: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/641843/webmatirx-offline-installer

Answer (score 1):

you can download offline installer from Web Platform Installer
Run on your PC with internet connection WebMatrixWeb.exe, click Install
You will see installation plan and [download link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/A/A/2AA5658E-7290-4DA0-89CB-06B3B6D59DCF/WebMatrix_x86_en-US.msi) on the right.

[this](https://www.computersnyou.com/1838/webmatrix-3-offline-download-and-install/) may help

Answer (score 0):

There's a link to an offline instaler for x86 available at [`download.microsoft.com/download/c/2/a/c2a485fa-013a-45ef-baba-c568e40f4b50/WebMatrix_x86_en-US.msi`](http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/2/a/c2a485fa-013a-45ef-baba-c568e40f4b50/WebMatrix_x86_en-US.msi). Requires IIS 7.5 Express or IIS 8.0 Express.

I can see you've specifically asked for x64 version, but this might work for someone searching for x86 version.